# Is it possible declare a variable and sets value later in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to keep track of nodes that are processed already and avoid processing them again when I call a template. 
I pass a node to a named template. The called template should avoid processing it if the node was already processed. I know the `<xsl:variable>` is not used for storing dynamic values. Is there something equivalent in XSLT?

### Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">
<bookmap>

    <topicref navtitle="First Topic" href="../topics/c_try_react.dita"/>

    <topicref navtitle="Second Topic" href="../topics/c_try_react.dita"/>

    <topicref navtitle="To Be Excluded" href="../topics/c_try_react.dita"/>

    <topicref navtitle="Fourth Topic" href="../topics/c_online_playgrounds.dita"/>

    <topicref navtitle="Fifth Topic" href="../topics/c_online_playgrounds.dita"/>

</bookmap>
```

### My Current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="uri:fn"
    xmlns:dita-ot="http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/ns/201007/dita-ot"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs dita-ot" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="html"/>
    <xsl:variable name="msgprefix">DOTX</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="newline">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- *************************** Command line parameters *********************** -->
    <xsl:param name="OUTEXT" select="'.html'"/>
    <!-- "htm" and "html" are valid values -->
    <xsl:param name="WORKDIR" select="'./'"/>
    <xsl:param name="processed-id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        <html>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <head> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            </head>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <body class="home-body">
                <div class="home-header-container" style="border-bottom:1px solid #C76E4D;">
                    <div id="header-home-logo">
                        <img src="ng-log.png"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-survey">
                        Your <a href="https://nextgenhealthcare.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_3a4YKBLYJ9aymfH">feedback </a> is important.
                    </div>
                    <div class="empty-clear"></div>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="home-div-header">

                </div>-->
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[contains(@class, ' map/map ')]">
        <table class="home-table">
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="#A4343A" class="home-first-row">
                    <th colspan="2"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="home-body">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[contains(@class, 'map/topicref')][position() mod 2 = 0]">
                    <tr class="home-row">
                        <td class="home-cell">

                            <xsl:call-template name="checkprocessingrole">
                               <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="position" select="./position()"/>                                
                            </xsl:call-template>

                        </td>
                        <td class="home-cell">

                            <xsl:call-template name="checkprocessingrole">
                               <xsl:with-param name="node" select="(following-sibling::*)[1]"/>
                               <xsl:with-param name="position" select="(following-sibling::*)[1]/position()"/>                                 
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="checkprocessingrole">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>

        <xsl:variable name="new" select="generate-id($node)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($node/@toc='no' or $node/@processing-role='resource-only')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$node/@navtitle"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$node/@toc='no' or $node/@processing-role='resource-only'">
                <xsl:call-template name="checkprocessingrole">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/(following-sibling::*)[1]"/>    
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Expected Result

I am trying to build a two-column table like the following by looping through the topicref elements in a ditamap file. 
[image]

### Rules

The table should contain only two columns. Each cell in a row contains the navtitle value. If a `<topicref>` has the attribute @processing-role set to "resource-only", it should be skipped. When a topicref element is skipped, no empty cell should be created.

### Actual Result

My current XSLT produces the following result:
[image]

Please note that the first topic title is not appearing in the table, which is correct. However, the second topic navtitle appears twice in the table, which should be avoided.

### XSLT Versions

The XSLT version can be either 1.0 or 2.0 but not 3.0.

Comment: How about a [mcve] that includes the input and expected output.

Comment: P.S. The answer to your question is no - but a recursive template can keep track of processed nodes by adding them to a parameter that's passed down to further calls.

Comment: Hi michael, could you please give me an example? I tried a few things but not working. I am not an XSLT expert. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: For example:  `<xsl:with-param name="processed-nodes" select="$processed-nodes | $node"/>`. Sorry, I don't have time to come up with a more complete example.

Comment: It might be easier for us to propose a more XSLT like approach if you show minimal but representatives samples of XML input and corresponding HTML result you want to create, together with a verbal description of the rules you want to implement. Also please state which version of XSLT you use/can use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I tried providing a sample input xml and the minimized version of my current XSLT. Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Does the current minimal input sample have no `@processing-role` attributes at all? In general, given that you use XSLT 2 and want to use some positional grouping, it seems doing e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="topicref[not(@processing-role = 'resource-only')]" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 2"><tr><td><xsl:value-of select="navtitle"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]/navtitle"/></td></tr></xsl:for-each-group>` seems all, i.e. positional grouping on a grouping population that already has a predidcate to exclude any nodes you don't want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you. I made the changes suggested by you and it worked. Thanks a ton. I posted your solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton to Martin Honnen.

As suggested by Martin Honnen, I changed the simple for-each loop to a for-each-group with group-adjacent. And it worked. 
Posting the solution (credit to Martin Honnen):

```
<xsl:template match="/*[contains(@class, ' map/map ')]">
        <table class="home-table">
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="#A4343A" class="home-first-row">
                    <th colspan="2"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="home-body">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*[contains(@class, 'map/topicref')][not(@processing-role='resource-only' or @toc='no')]" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 2">
                    <tr class="home-row">
                        <td class="home-cell">
                            <xsl:call-template name="get-document">
                                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                        <td class="home-cell">
                            <xsl:call-template name="get-document">
                                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="current-group()[2]"/>                          
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Now that you have the positional grouping in place, note that in general, to avoid spelling out the same code for each table cell, you could, inside of the `tr` element, simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` and then you would set up a template matching those elements that creates the `td`. I am not sure what the named template `get-document` does, but there might even be a way to avoid the rather verbose `call-template` and simply use template matching, if needed with a different mode.

Comment: The input xml I that added here is a very basic one. The `get-document` template uses the` href` attribute to load the document and then get the title. The `topicrefs` will not always have a `navtitle`. In some circumstances, the `topicrefs` can be attributes of  chapter elements. I am still figuring out what magic the position()-1 idiv 2 does, by debugging the processing. :)

Comment: `position()` for the items in the grouping population (e.g. the `*[contains(@class, 'map/topicref')][not(@processing-role='resource-only' or @toc='no')]`) will be `1,2,3,4,...` and `(position() - 1)` will be `0,1,2,3,...`. Finally `(position() - 1) idiv 2` will be `0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...` so that way the first two items will be grouped together (in your case to form a row/`tr`),  the third and the fourth, the fifth and the sixth, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

It's not permited to do that.
It just can declarate a new variable to be assigned the value, Or You can return the new value in a function to override the value. like that

```
<xsl:variable name="v1" select="()">
<xsl:variable name="v1" select="some_function_call(...)">
```

If the two "v1" in different scope. they maybe two different variables. Note that the low scope variable can't change value of the prev one variable with same name .

Ok, for your example code, you can use the  [xsl:where-populated](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-where-populated) or [xsl:on-non-empty](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#on-non-empty) to omit which has the attribute @processing-role.

As you just ouput two columns with omitted items, I suggest you to use "xsl:iterate" with "xsl:with-param" to calc the count of items ouputed. When the count of outputed items is even, insert a `<tr>` before the item; when the count of outputed items is odd, append a `</tr>` after the item.

There are so many ways to reach your target. I think my answer is more flexible, you can change the count of columns what you want, just calc the count of ouputed items, then mod the column's count.